# Thousand of roues with Node.js / Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm learning Node.js / Express.

I understand how to use router with something like:

```
const productsRouter = require('./routes/products');
const employeesRouter = require('./routes/employees');

app.use('/products', productsRouter);
app.use('/employees', employeesRouter);
```

I wonder, how to deal with dozen of routes. I don't speak about URL parameters, just routes.

Should I create dozen of modules ? And copy the above line dozens of times? Is there a more elegant and concise solution ?

Comment: Depending on how complex the routes are, having them in separate modules seems rather elegant to me. Or are they more-or-less boilerplate code with just a few changes in each individual route? In that case, _one generic route_ might be the better solution.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thank you for the answer. Case 1: my routes are independent. Is there a way to use a single route in the main file and dispatch in the root router?

Comment: Of course you can include all the code in one file, provided that your variable names don't clash. But "single route" means just one `app.use` statement, why would you want that?

Comment: I was't clear, I wonder if I can create a main router that call sub routers? And sub router calls sub sub router and so on?

Answer (score -1):

```
you can group all your routes in the routes folder

    |-- app.js
    |-- routes
    |   |-- index.js
    |   |-- router1.js
    |   |-- router2.js
    |   |-- routes.js

in routes.js import all the routes 



  module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(express.json());

  app.use("/", indexRouter);
  app.use("/router1", router1Router);
  app.use("/router2", router2Router);
};




And in App.js only import routes.js:



    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    require("./startup/routes")(app);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).